# Creating a stacked Column graph in R without ggplot

Tags: r, bar-chart, stacked

I have a data

```
    equip ballots  freq %Undercounts
1   LEVER  427780 17016         3.98
2 OPTICAL 1436159 39090         2.72
3   PAPER    3454   113         3.27
4   PUNCH  823921 38462         4.67
```

I want to plot equipment on the X-axis. And ballots should be at 100% for each equip. Freq should be the percentage of the bars and be represented as a percentage of ballots.

I have tried `barplot` and lattice plots. But I'm getting some error which seems like my data is not in form. Can someone please help me in what I might be missing.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to accomplish with `lattice`

```
barchart(freq/ballots + (ballots-freq)/ballots ~ equip, tab, stack=TRUE)
```

[image]

Base graphics require more code and some obscure parameter tweaking to look good

```
attach(tab)
barplot(rbind(freq/ballots, 1), width=.8, space=.25)
mtext(equip, side=1, at=1:nrow(tab)-.4)
```

[image]